# Springboot URl mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the controller method like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginProcess(@RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("password") String password,
        HttpSession session) {

    session.setAttribute("email", email);
    Optional<User> userDetail = userRepository.findById(email);

    if (userDetail.isPresent()) {
        String userType = userDetail.get().getUserType();
        String passwordDb = userDetail.get().getPassword();
        if (password.equals(passwordDb) && userType.equals("admin")) {
            return "adminPage";
        } else if (password.equals(passwordDb) && userType.equals("candidate")) {
            return "candidatePage";
        } else {
            return "passwordError";
        }

    } else {
        return "invalid";
    }
```

I have URL localhost:8080/login/do as URL 
for my login process method inside the method, some business logic is written upon execution of that it will take me to some page candidate.html,passworderror.html, etc however on moving to the any of the pages the URL is showing as localhost:8080/login/candidate.jsp here I don't want /login to be present in URL.
strong text
since here onwards moving on to any page if i move forward the localhost:8080**/

> **login****

/candidate.jsp is present by default. 
expected  Url should not include login further.

Comment: Do not invent your own security scheme. Use Spring Security. (And for that matter, I recommend Thymeleaf instead of JSP for views.)

Answer (score 0):

remove from properties file if exists:
`server.servlet.context-path=`

and also specify where your jsp pages are created and also mention your properties file configuration and @Controller annotation code as well.